# How do I include default module styles on Divi custom modules when Dynamic CSS is enabled?

Tags: wordpress, themes, divi

I've created a custom module based on Divi's Blog module. Ever since the 4.10 the module's grid layout does not work anymore because of the Dynamic CSS feature. When this is enabled Divi basically only loads the required assets when a specific module is used. So if the Divi Blog Module is not in the page the required CSS is not included and my custom module displays bad.

I saw a filter that should force the assets of a default module and used it inside my custom module:

```
//force the blog assets to be included inside this custom module
function include_module_assets($assets_list) {
    return ['et_pb_blog'];
}
add_filter( 'et_required_module_assets', 'include_module_assets' );
```

Now this adds some column styles, but the column widths are not being set. So there are still some styles that are not being loaded.

Anybody experienced this yet with their Divi extensions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divi dynamic asset loading for custom modules can be quite frustrating.
Always check `Divi/includes/builder/feature/dynamic-assets/class-dynamic-assets.php` for all the required CSS AND JS dependencies.

For a custom Blog, first, you have to load the basic dependencies with `et_required_module_assets` filter:

```php
function fzs_divi_check_if_module_exists($module, $content) {
    $content = is_string( $content ) ? $content : '';
    $module_exists = preg_match( '/\[' . $module . ' /', $content );
    return $module_exists;
}

add_filter('et_required_module_assets', 'fzs_custom_module_dependencies', 10, 2);
function fzs_custom_module_dependencies($required_assets, $all_content) {
    $blog_module_slug = 'your_custom_blog_slug'; //replace as you want
    if (fzs_divi_check_if_module_exists($blog_module_slug, $all_content)) {
        array_push($required_assets, 'et_pb_blog'); //Load blog CSS
        //Load (the very outdated and abandoned) salvattore
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'salvattore',
            ET_BUILDER_URI . '/feature/dynamic-assets/assets/js/salvattore.js',
            array(), ET_CORE_VERSION, true
        );
    }

    return $required_assets;
}
```

Then, for some modules (like Blog), which require grids, you also have to load them with `et_global_assets_list` filter:

```php
add_filter('et_global_assets_list', 'fzs_add_dynamic_grid_dependencies', 10, 3);
function fzs_add_dynamic_grid_dependencies($early_global_asset_list, $assets_args, $dynamic_assets_class) {
    $gutter_widths = $assets_args['gutter_widths'];
    $gutter_length = $assets_args['gutter_length'];
    $speciality = $assets_args['specialty_used'];
    $grid_items = true; //Must be true for Blog grid
    $early_global_asset_list['fzs_custom_grid_dependencies'] = 
        $dynamic_assets_class->get_gutters_asset_list(
            $gutter_length, $gutter_widths, $speciality, $grid_items
        );
    return $early_global_asset_list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As there doesn't seem to be a filter for *$grid_items_deps* found in *ET_Dynamic_Assets::get_global_assets_list* you can use the *et_global_assets_list* filter.

You'll probably find you need to *add_filter* earlier than when your module class is initialized, perhaps one level back in the constructor of your extension class.

```
function init() {
    parent::init();

    /** Removed other code the sake of simplicity **/

    add_filter( 'et_required_module_assets', array($this,  'include_module_assets') );
}

// Make sure we include gutters3_grid_items
public function include_early_global_assets($global_asset_list, $assets_args, $dynamic_assets_class){
    $assets_prefix    = et_get_dynamic_assets_path();
    $gutters_3_grid_path = $assets_prefix . '/css/gutters3_grid_items.css';
    $global_asset_list['some_custom_blog'] = array(
        'css' => $gutters_3_grid_path
    );
    return $global_asset_list;
}
```

Hopefully ET adds a filter in the future for *$grid_items_deps* in the near future. They do seem to be getting a little better with providing filters, still many more could be added.

If anyone knows of a better solution I'd be keen know, as there is an issue with the below that we include gutters3_grid_items.css even when not using a grid layout.

Cheers